# Why is datetime not what expected and how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I can't figure out why rails datetime is not matching up. The below test fails because my created_at date is not identical, but I don't know why

Test

```
it "renders the course as json" do
  course = create(:course)
  get :index, format: :json
  expect(response.body).to eq [course].to_json
end
```

Output

```
CoursesController
  GET #index - json
    renders the #index view (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) CoursesController GET #index - json renders the #index view
     Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq [course].to_json

       expected: "[{\"id\":2,\"partner_id\":2,\"name\":\"MyCourse 1\",\"created_at\":\"2014-08-29T10:49:06.205+02:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-08-29T10:49:06.205+02:00\",\"status\":\"active\"}]"
            got: "[{\"id\":2,\"partner_id\":2,\"name\":\"MyCourse 1\",\"created_at\":\"2014-08-29T10:49:06.000+02:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-08-29T10:49:06.000+02:00\",\"status\":\"active\"}]"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/courses_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more investigation, it seems that when saving to MySQL some precision is lost. To correct the issue all I do is `course.reload` and the precisions now match.